Add a blank space when an empty tag in XML is encountered
Im using Apache FOP to create PDFs.
Part of my XML looks like below. Basically i am trying to put the entire content of the tags as is in the PDF and I'm having a bit of challenge here.
I would like to have an blank space when there is an empty TEXT tag:
"<Text></Text>"

XML:
    <Text>NUMBER             :   123456      ABCDE     -  ASBI</Text>
    <Text>REFERENCENUMBER    : TECNO - ENOS-B</Text>
    <Text></Text>
    <Text>USER   1           : COMPANY XYZ</Text>
    <Text>                     TECH CENTER1</Text>
    <Text>                     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX X XX</Text>
    <Text>                     0000 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Text>
    <Text>USER   2           : COMPANY MNO</Text>
    <Text>                     TECH CENTER2</Text>
    <Text>                     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX X XX</Text>
    <Text>                     0000 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Text>
    <Text></Text>
    <Text>QTY. SUBSCRIPTION PRICE, OPTICAL CAPACITY</Text>

My code consists of a for-each block on the node Text:
                            <xsl:for-each select="Text">
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block font-family="Courier" font-size="7pt" font-weight="normal" display-align="center" white-space="pre">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </xsl:for-each>

Im able to achieve the blank spaces in the tag using the White-space="pre". But how do i get a blank line?
My output looks like below:
    NUMBER             :   123456      ABCDE     -  ASBI
    REFERENCENUMBER    : TECNO - ENOS-B 
    USER   1           : COMPANY XYZ
                           TECH CENTER1
                         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX X XX
                         0000 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    USER   2           : COMPANY MNO
                         TECH CENTER2
                         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX X XX
                         0000 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    QTY. SUBSCRIPTION PRICE, OPTICAL CAPACITY

Expected output :
    NUMBER             :   123456      ABCDE     -  ASBI
    REFERENCENUMBER    : TECNO - ENOS-B 

    USER   1           : COMPANY XYZ
                           TECH CENTER1
                         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX X XX
                         0000 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    USER   2           : COMPANY MNO
                         TECH CENTER2
                         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX X XX
                         0000 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    QTY. SUBSCRIPTION PRICE, OPTICAL CAPACITY


Try whether <fo:table empty-cells="show" ...>...</fo:table> changes/improves things.

Nope dint work :( I have figured out a workaround though. Posting the answer below.

Your white-space="pre" shorthand also preserves linefeeds, as it also sets linefeed-treatment="preserve". (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#white-space and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#linefeed-treatment)
So you can put all of your Text in one fo:block and generate a linefeed after the string value of each Text:
<xsl:template match="Block">
  <fo:block font-family="Courier" font-size="7pt" white-space="pre">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Text" />
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Text">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

The empty Text generate only a linefeed.
You didn't show what goes around your Text, so I made up a Block element.

I added a check and it worked:
         <xsl:for-each select="Text">
                            <fo:table-row >
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block font-family="Courier" font-size="7pt" font-weight="normal" display-align="center" white-space="pre">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) = 0">
                                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </xsl:for-each>

